# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта во время binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, livechart

Всем добрый вечер! Пытаюсь сделать binding к элементу на форме wpf, но вылезает ошибка: **Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта**. Моя xaml форма имеет следующий код:
`<lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1" VisualElements="{Binding Visuals}" Name="chart" />`
А сама коллекция для binding образуется следующим образом:

```
    public VisualElementsCollection visuals;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        visuals = new VisualElementsCollection();

        visuals = new VisualElementsCollection
        {
            new VisualElement
            {
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                UIElement = new EventAControl()
            },
            new VisualElement

            {

                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                UIElement = new EventBControl()
            }
        };

        DataContext = this;


    }
    public VisualElementsCollection Visuals
    { 
        get
        {
            return visuals;
        }
        set
        {
            visuals = value;
            INotifyPropertyChanged("Visuals");
        }
    }
```

Как можно исправить инициализацию объекта, чтобы ошибка это не выходила? Изменил код добавил INotifyPropertyChanged, но все равно ничего не выводит.
Определение класса VisualElementsCollection

```
    public class VisualElementsCollection : NoisyCollection<ICartesianVisualElement>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of VisualElementsCollection
    /// </summary>
    public VisualElementsCollection()
    {
        NoisyCollectionChanged += OnNoisyCollectionChanged;
    }
```

public ChartCore Chart { get; set; }

```
    private void OnNoisyCollectionChanged(IEnumerable<ICartesianVisualElement> oldItems, IEnumerable<ICartesianVisualElement> newItems)
    {
        if (oldItems != null) foreach (var oltItem in oldItems) oltItem.Remove(Chart);
        if (newItems != null) foreach (var newItem in newItems) newItem.AddOrMove(Chart);
    }
```

Объявление класса  NoisyCollection:

```
public class NoisyCollection<T> : INoisyCollection, IList<T>
{
    #region Private Fields
    private readonly object _sync = new object();
    private readonly List<T> _source;
    private const string CountString = "Count";
    private const string IndexerString = "Item[]";
    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of NoisyCollection class
    /// </summary>
    public NoisyCollection()
    {
        _source = new List<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of NoisyCollection class with a given collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">given collection</param>
    public NoisyCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _source = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of NoisiCollection class with a given capacity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capacity">given capacity</param>
    public NoisyCollection(int capacity)
    {
        _source = new List<T>(capacity);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when [collection reset].
    /// </summary>
    public event Action CollectionReset;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when [noisy collection changed].
    /// </summary>
    event NoisyCollectionCollectionChanged<object> INoisyCollection.NoisyCollectionChanged
    {
        add { NoisyCollectionChanged += value as NoisyCollectionCollectionChanged<T>; }
        remove { NoisyCollectionChanged -= value as NoisyCollectionCollectionChanged<T>; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when [noisy collection changed].
    /// </summary>
    public event NoisyCollectionCollectionChanged<T> NoisyCollectionChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the collection changes.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            PropertyChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            PropertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets an item from/in a specific index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">index to get/set</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _source[index];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            var original = this[index];
            lock (_sync)
            {
                _source[index] = value;
            }
            ReplaceItem(original, value, index);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets an item from/in a specific index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">index to get/set</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _source[index];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            var original = this[index];
            lock (_sync)
            {
                _source[index] = (T)value;
            }
            ReplaceItem(original, value, index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А зачем инициализировать `Visuals` на `Window_Loaded`? Что мешает сделать это в конструкторе?

Comment: Подозреваю, нужно использовать INPC

Comment: @Ev_Hyper я добавил INPC. но у меня не сработало. Я изменил код в вопросе. может я что-то не так сделал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут сразу видно несколько проблем.

Во-первых, как правильно подсказывает @Ev_Hyper, вы должны реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, чтобы ваши изменения подхватывались.

Во-вторых, если вы используете MVVM, то привязываться вы должны не к свойствам окна, а к свойствам вашего `DataContext`'а. А если вы всё же хотите почему-то привязаться к свойствам окна, вы должны установить на него `DataContext` (или поменять `Source`/`RelativeSource` в привязке.

Ну и в третьих, привязка *имеет право* вернуть `null` в промежуточные моменты, так что ваш код внутри `lvc:CartesianChart` не должен падать, если привязка ничего не возвращает.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59831/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd--------).

Answer (score 0):

А пробовали задать в `Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}"` в xaml разметке где `SeriesCollection` Ваша коллекция?!

Comment: к сожалению я так и делал и так не работает